# Making a View for the first use of an app

Tags: ios, storyboard, launch

I wish to make an app that, when the user opens it for the first time he selects his country from a picker in order to make his flag appear on the main screen. If the user closes the app and opens it again I want the app to start the menu screen with his flag on it directly.

I am using the following code now but it doesn't work at all. Every time the app is opened it takes him to the picker VIew (TappViewController)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"FirstLaunch"]) {

        secViewController *menu = [[secViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:menu animated:YES completion:^{

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"FirstLaunch"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];}];
    }
    else{

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"FirstLaunch"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
```

Comment: you are checking in wrong way, your if condition should be like......... if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"FirstLaunch"])

Comment: True, added the "!" though and the outcome was the same. I don't get errors but the code does absolutely nothing..

Comment: Above code should work now,if not plz check if app is clearing user-default while closing app or while going to background (within some AppDelegate method).

Comment: Oh,didn't think of that! Might work, will try it out now, thank you! p.S will let you know if it works

Comment: @mhrrt Nope, I did not modify anything in the app delegate. What else could be clearing my defaults? It would make sense if that was happening

Comment: put log within each delegate method in AppDelegate.m for NSUserDefault and check if you are loosing NSUserDefault values at any of the delegate method, thats the only thing i can suggest for now.

Comment: @mhrrt think i've figured out what the problem is. i've kept running and closing the emulator, it does not think it is the first time it is opened. the problem is with the code that takes me to the other view. that does not perform.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isPickerOpened"]) {

        secViewController *menu = [[secViewController alloc] init];

        [self presentViewController:menu animated:YES completion:^{

             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"isPickerOpened"];
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed the code to what you suggested. Still have no errors but every time I close the app or the whole emulator and try again to open it it takes me to the picker. No errors no anything. It works just as if the code isn't there

Comment: Yeap, you updated it half an hour ago, I have the exact code that is up there now. Still nothing... the code does make perfect sense. I just don't get why it doesn't do anything....

Comment: just played around with it a bit. added a background both to the if and to the else. if i add the background color to the if (to the exact code you have suggested) the apps's bckground color will be red every time i launch it. if i add it to tthe else, nothing happens

Comment: set breakPoint into completion block and check if it's passing to this block. If it's passed into block then check /Users/YourUserName/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/9ABF9F6D-317A-4C25-915D-757A89A209CE/Library/Preferences/com.yourTeamName.yourAppName.plist. Can You found isPickerOpened value in the .plist file?

Comment: @ShamsiddinSaidov didn't see your last comment. The booleans are fine. i made a simple example. i added a blue background if the app is opened for the first time and a red one if it has been opened before. they work perfectly. the problem is with the code that should send the user to the other screen if the app has been opened before. it's like it doesn'to do anything.